# Boostrap tooltips stopped working when angular added to page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3.3.5 with tooltips like so:

```
<input type="text" id="lat" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Optional; Format:  III.DDDD" />
```

Working perfect, then I added angular.js, v1.4.5 and all tooltips reverted to stock HTML.  I have started looking into it, and it seems I have to use angular-ui. Is this the solution, or is there a better work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the above suggestions, no help.  I ended up adding Angular-UI

```
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
```

tooltips now working.

Answer (score 0):

Tries to call a tooltip using javascript:

```
$("#lat").tooltip({
    placement: "top",
    title: "Optional; Format:  III.DDDD"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that there is a problem with loading jQuery and AngularJS together.

From the Angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) :

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.

Meaning that if you want to use the **$** jQuery identifier, you would have to pass `angular.element` as an instance of jQuery. The following code allows you to initialize all the tooltips on your page (taken from [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)):

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

If you want to use this code in your AngularJS application, you would have to pass the jQuery instance, like so:

```
(function($){
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
})(angular.element);
```

Whenever you are using the **$** sign, you are referring to `angular.element`, which means jQuery object in this case, due to the addition of the library in your code.

I have created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOaMmY?p=preview), which allows for dynamic update of the tooltip title, via a combination between jQuery and AngularJS.

Hope this helps!

Thank you and have a nice day!